# The way of the creation sql-query in java code

Tags: java, sql, database, jpa

I'm developing a site and using java, jsp and jpa. The aim of the site is to give an interface for user to select data from database. It requires forming complicated sql-queries and that is a reason why I have chosen jpa. Now I start to think "Is this choice right?". Why?

1. Is it possible to use criteria api for creating complicated sql-queries with 3-4 join clauses?
2. Is it possible to use stored procedures in select clause (in criteria api), like "   select "hypDate", "MacrosAsString"("mcrDcpId", "mcrMinIntensity") from ...  "?
3. As it turned out, I can't pass array as a parameter in stored procedure. It gives me exception "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.util.Arrays$ArrayList. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use."

I'm new in java, that's why I need your help. Is there alternatives that give opportunity to form sql query in java code like criteria api? Or maybe I'm complicating a situation and jpa solves three problems above and I simple don't know how?

P.S. My realization of JPA is EclipseLink and database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Not constructive I know, but the answer to this type of question is, as always, "That depends."

Comment: Maybe the question in the title is not concrete. I'm looking for the way of the creation sql-query in java code like criteria api does or a piece of advice about those three problems in question.

Comment: I've changed the title. Now it's more proper.